# android time calculator example code (help)

Tags: android, time

I am a little bit confused by the date formatter/calander and all the formats that are related to the time. I am trying to get the current time with no date and, although I have seen several code snippets this still confuses me. 
My problem is the following is to get current time and send it to some method for some calculations.

---

**For example**

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){.... 
   .........
   ........
    **get the current time**
     sendToMethod(currentTime)
   }

   public void sendToMethod(currentTime)
   {
     Date pastTime
     long diff = currentTime - pastTime;
     if (diff > 1000)  // here i want to check if the diffrence is more then 10 seconds
    // do something
    }
```

---

I searched and tried several codes but I got lost. 
I found that there are alot of ways to do this, but I still have no clue how to solve this. 
Please, if anyone can help me I will appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Joda time. 
No Joda time:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds/minutes/hours/etc = c.get(Calendar.SECOND/MINUTE/HOUR/etc);
```

In Joda Time:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();  
// where January is 1 and December is 12
int year = dt.getYear();
```

**Edit** 
If you want to get the current time:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

using the current time and the some time in the past you can find the
difference. Time in the past can be obtained via the codes from above.

[Joda Time User Guide](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html)

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand anything from the link

Comment: It is the general Joda time user guide for you to read. However, I copy-pasted you the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private long diff, start = System.currentTimeMillis();
public void sendToMethod()
{        
     diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
     if (diff > 10000) { // difference is more then 10 seconds
         // do something
     }

     start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sendToMethod(currentTime);
}

public void sendToMethod(long currentTime) {

    long diff = currentTime - pastTime;
    if (diff > 10000){
        // Do some thing here...
    }
}
```